# how to fly in div from bottom of wrapper upwards

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to fly up a div `.alert` in it's wrapper from the bottom of the wrapper 40 px higher.
 But i do not succeed in it the put the alert div start at the bottom of the wrapper. It should start at the bottom line and then go up 40px and then stop. But it starts at the top of the wrapper and then goes out of it

```
.wrapper {
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #333;
}
.alert {
  width: 360px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: flyup 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  bottom: 0px;
}

@keyframes flyup {
  0%   {background: green; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;}
  100% {background: green; left: 0px; bottom: 40px;}
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="alert">This content should fly up 40px upwards in 2 seconds</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfz4rb5d/

Comment: So should the alert fly up 40px, or fly up to 40px from the top?

Comment: 40 px up, and the alert should start at the bottom of the wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `position: relative` to the `.wrapper` and `position: absolute` to the `.alert`. This causes the `.alert` to be positioned relative to the `.wrapper`.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.alert {
  width: 360px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation: flyup 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  bottom: 0px;
}

@keyframes flyup {
  0% {
    background: green;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="alert">This content should fly up 40px to the top in 2 seconds</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i was looking for